# Vertical alignment with cases

Tags: alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    
    \item Determine:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \item $r \equiv (x,y)=(2,1)+\lambda(1,-1)$
                
                \item $ s \equiv
                    \begin{cases}
                        x=3+2\mu \\
                        y=4+3\mu \\
                    \end{cases}
                    $
            \end{multicols}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can a align i. and ii. vertically?

Comment: It took me some effort to compile your code, but more importantly there is no (b) to align. So where's your issue?

Comment: I meant i) and ii), it was another enumerate deeper

Comment: OK, I see what you want. You'd like to have i. and ii. on the same line. And since the second line is actually 2 (maybe even 3) lines high, the i. and ii. aren't aligned vertically.
I personally think that it'll look bad whatever you do as long as you try to keep i. and ii. on the same line. IOW I'd omit the multicols

Answer (score 0):

Not really brilliant, but nevertheless I'll share my result

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    
    \item Determine:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
        \begin{enumerate}
            %\begin{multicols}{2}
                \item $r \equiv (x,y)=(2,1)+\lambda(1,-1)$
                
                \item $ s \equiv
                    \begin{cases}
                        x=3+2\mu \\
                        y=4+3\mu \\
                    \end{cases}
                    $
            %\end{multicols}
        \end{enumerate}
        \item
        \begin{enumerate}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \item \rule{0pt}{4ex}$r \equiv (x,y)=(2,1)+\lambda(1)$
                
                \item $ s \equiv
                    \begin{cases}
                        x=3+2\mu \\
                        y=4+3\mu \\
                    \end{cases}
                    $
            \end{multicols}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And yes, the zero pt wide rule is (positively stated) super ugly, but as long as it is an exception, it might be tolerable